# org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'personService'

Tags: java, spring-boot, maven, heroku-api

I need help for understand the error on my application, help me !

**Error console**

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'personController' defined in file [D:\IntelliJ\projetcs\personapi\target\classes\one\digitalinnovation\personapi\controller\PersonController.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'personService' defined in file [D:\IntelliJ\projetcs\personapi\target\classes\one\digitalinnovation\personapi\service\PersonService.class]: Bean instantiation via constructor failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [one.digitalinnovation.personapi.service.PersonService]: Constructor threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
```

Answer (score 2):

As the exception message said:

```
[one.digitalinnovation.personapi.service.PersonService]: Constructor threw exception
```

*PersonService* constructor has thrown an exception. Double check that constructor, debug it or surround the constructor code with a try...catch to log the root cause of the exception

Comment: I am used annotation @AllArgsConstructor(onConstructor = @__(@Autowired))